# Run python script automatically on apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, python, scripting

I have a hello world script written in python called hello.py. I am using apache on a windows machine, and I'd like the script to run automatically, whenever I enter something like http://localhost/

Can someone please tell me how to do this ?

PS: If I point to the script directly from the browser, it displays properly.

hello.py:

```
#! c:\Python27\python.exe

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print 'Heya, world..yaba daba doo!'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your Python script to be the index document?

If your setup already works when you do something like http://localhost/hello.py  I would suggest renaming it to `index.py` (common convention to call an index document "index.something") and then editing your Apache configuration to include index.py inthe `DirectoryIndex` filenames list.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend you write your app (however simple) around a framework.  It makes everything massively easier, and you don't end up reinventing wheels.  I tend to use [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), or [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/).

I recommend you give Cherry a look.  The homepage details how to make a Hello World application.
Then all you need to do is ProxyPass to it from Apache, or use mod_wsgi and let apache communicate directly with the application.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `DirectoryIndex` set appropriately in your `httpd.conf` file?

For example, my `DirectoryIndex` line is as follows - you should add hello.py to the list (although index.py may be more conventional).

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`